# VSTS Release Management > Deploy AzureRM Web App > ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have set up a release definition with the Deploy AzureRM Web App task. However, OFTENTIMES when it runs it throws the following error:

```
Error Code: ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED More Information: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TE RMINATED.
##[error] Error: Root element is missing.
##[error] Error count: 1.
```

To solve the problem currently, without any changes to the definition, I have to rerun the release and it ran successfully. Just some information, I have 1 task before and 1 task after the Deploy AzureRM task: stop the Web App and start the Web App.

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to this task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment

If it's your case, you can see in the description,

> The task is under development

and also,

> Please contact the alias RM_Customer_Queries at microsoft dot com, if you are facing problems in making this task work. Also, share feedback about the task, and the new features that you would like to see in it.

Comment: thanks i will keep a look out when it becomes a stable release